# Linking recipients inside a disclaimer

Tags: html, email, office365

I am setting up a disclaimer for our work emails inside office 365 exchange admin centre.

After doing a lot of research and hitting my head against the wall, I still cannot find out how you can do this.

So to start off, I am going to office 365 and type ecp after portal.office.com in the url bar:

Then I go to mail flow on the left, press the + button and press Apply disclaimers.
[image]

What I want it to do is to display the following:

This email and any files transmitted with it are confidential and intended solely for meant for email1@domain.com; email2@domain.com; etc..only....

like in the image here:

[image: Image2]

After researching I have found that there is 15 attributes you can use in disclaimer to customize it, unfortunately none of them will display the recipients email addresses, and the most I can get by using attribute %%email%%
Does anyone know how you can set it up or which rule you need to use for the disclaimer to display the email addresses that the email is intended for?